# Impact of thread without name in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have various Thread in my java application with syntax

```
new Thread(this).start();
```

When I performed Code Audit using [Code Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro) I have got following message

```
Thread declare without a name.
```

I wants to know what does it mean and is it ok if I change the declaration to

```
new Thread(this,this.getName()).start();
```

What is the difference between them and their impact. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your lint is just recommended that you create your thread with a name.  That is to use the new Thread(Runnable, String) constructor.

Comment: Note that `new Thread(this.getName())` won't set the `Runnable`, so it will probably only work if you're extending `Thread`.

Comment: @BrendanLong Thanks for pointing that out, I have modified my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just Code Pro's polite way of reminding you that a thread should have an identifying name, for easier debugging if it comes to that. It doesn't have any more "impact" beyond that, it's simply a good programming practice. This should work:

```
new Thread(this, "an identifying name").start();
```

Notice that `this.getName()` will only work if you already defined a name to be returned by `getName()` in the current class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice clarification

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the thread now has the name you give it instead of a default name. Apparently someone considers that important enough to hold up an audit. I certainly do not.

Comment: Actually, it is if you want to monitor threads for activity, contention, etc. Those generic names created by Executors default thread factory don't give away much information then, which is why we always use our own. Not sure if it should be an issue for audits, though :)

Comment: @RalfH It can be helpful in that circumstance, if the code doesn't work. It's not worth holding up a code audit for IMHO. I don't believe in letting software tell me how to spend development money. If the code doesn't work someone will have to debug it and maybe add the name. I do multithreading all the time (who doesn't?) and the last time I named a thread was about ten years ago.